# Dreamspark windows 8.1 embedded update to windows 8

Tags: windows

I just Got verified from Dream spark. I am downloading Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro with Update 32bit Update. And I am using windows 8.

What that update will do? will it register my windows? What is the benefit ?

Comment: What? Your question is not clear grammaticaly

Comment: Sir I just got verified from Microsoft Dreamspark, There is a download (Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro with Update). Will this update will upgrade my windows to 8.1 from Windows 8 pro ?

Comment: Do you mean "with Update 1" full why are there two questions about this exact topic

Comment: Yeah will it update to windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Yes;  All versions of Windows 8 are eligible to be updated to 8.1.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use Embedded on a physical workstation. I have DreamSpark still, and I just use the server OS versions, as all my stuff is really servers. Workstations I install from my MSDN subscription.

Comment: @EdG - Doesn't matter if it can be used on a workstation or not, it can be updated to 8.1, which was the question the author had.

Comment: The embedded version?

Comment: Thanks Guys ! My windows 8 pro is updated to windows embedded 8.1 successfully with Dream spark key !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro is a special [Version of Windows Embedded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_8#Editions) which is used for  devices like POS terminals, kiosks and scanners.

To update to Windows 8.1, simply [use the Windows store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial), here you find a link to make the upgrade to 8.1.